# Programatically showing/hiding bootstrap tooltips in Angular4

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Is it somehow possible to programatically show/hide tooltip on many elements in Angular4?

I have an errorField directive which emits an event when it receives an error from a subscription it subscribes to, I would like to show a tooltip with the error I received from the subscription in that event.

It works as it should in our AngularJS codebase because there we inject uib-tooltip in our errorfield directive in the compile phase and can in the link phase just show or hide it.

**compile phase**

```
element.attr('uib-tooltip',"{{errorMessage}}")
element.attr('tooltip-trigger', '{"show": "hide"}')
element.attr('tooltip-placement', 'auto')
if (attrs.appendErrorFieldToBody == "true") {
  element.attr('tooltip-append-to-body', true)
}
element.removeAttr('error-field')
```

**link phase**

```
fireCustomEvent(iElement, 'show')
```

I know how to manage this on just one element in Angular4.

```
@ViewChild('tooltip'): tooltip.
<input #tooltip="ngbTooltip">
this.tooltip.open();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the value of an attribute to `null` the attribute will be removed:

```
<div [attr.uib-tooltip]="showTooltip ? errorMessage : null>
```

(similar for the other attributes)